# How to get an array from a route?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-devops

I have an azure webjobs function and I need to get either an array or string back. The function definition is as follows.

```
    [FunctionName("GetFilteredEorInstancesByStatusOrganisationId")]
    [OpenApiOperation(operationId: "GetFilteredEorInstancesStatusByOrganisationId", tags: new[] { "reads" })]
    [OpenApiSecurity("function_key", SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey, Name = "code", In = OpenApiSecurityLocationType.Query)]
    [OpenApiParameter(name: "organisationId", In = ParameterLocation.Path, Required = true, Type = typeof(string), Description = "the id of the Organisation")]
    [OpenApiParameter(name: "searchFilter", In = ParameterLocation.Path, Required = true, Type = typeof(string), Description = "the search text filter")]
    [OpenApiParameter(name: "status", In = ParameterLocation.Path, Required = true, Type = typeof(string), Description = "the status text filter")]
    [OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: "text/json", bodyType: typeof(JObject), Description = "OK response")]
    [OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.NotFound, contentType: "text/plain", bodyType: typeof(string), Description = "NOT FOUND response")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetFilteredEorInstancesByStatusOrganisationId(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "organisations/{organisationId}/eorinstances/filters/{searchFilter}/statuses/{status}")]
        HttpRequest req, string organisationId, string searchFilter, [FromUri(Name ="status")] List<string> status)
```

I use the get request "http://localhost:7071/api/organisations/xxx/eorinstances/filters/xxx/statuses/status[0]=xxx". I have tried using FromQuery and FromRoute along with a multitude of get requests I have seen online. Does anyone know a working way to do this with routing on azure functions?

Answer (score 1):

> To fetch the route as a string, I have followed the below approach.

Below is the code to fetch the route as a string.

```
    using System.Net;
    using Azure;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    
    namespace FunctionApp14
    {
        public class Function1
        {
            private readonly ILogger _logger;
    
            public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
            {
                _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
            }
    
            [Function("Function1")]
             public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "{param1}/{param2}")] HttpRequestData req,
     string param1, string param2)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            _logger.LogInformation($"param1: {param1}");
            _logger.LogInformation($"param2: {param2}");

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

            response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]